# how to use angular service inside rxjs retryWhen method

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I am making the http service calls 3 times when i get 401 error using the retryWhen method form Rxjs operators. My problem is when i get 401 error as status i need to make other service to get the token updated and then re-try the http service call 3 times . I am unable to use service inside retryWhen call back method as it always showing this as undefined . Can you please provide me solution for this.

```
 return this.http.get(url, this.getOptions(options)).retryWhen(errors => {
       return errors.mergeMap((error) => {
            console.error('error status....', this, error, error.status);
            if (error.status === 401) {
                // i need to make other service call here 
                this.httpPollingService.updateToken(); // unable to call this call.
                return Observable.of(error);
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
        }).delay(5000).take(2);
    });
```

Comment: Are you saying that the `this` reference is `undefined` or that the `this.httpPollingService` is `undefined`?

Comment: Yes `this ` is `undefined` .

Comment: Can you change it to include where this code is? Eg what function this is returning from, is it inside a class, etc. Need to see where httpPollingService is assigned to the object.

Comment: Hi ,Here code how was doing , ` post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
        return this.http.post(url, body, this.getOptions(options)).retryWhen(this.generatorNewToken);

Answer (score 0):

I make it the following way to refresh token when 401 error status and and calling the same request method again with updated Token.

```js
 return this.http.post(url, body, headers).catch(initialError => {
            if (initialError.status === 401) {
                return this.newTokenGenerator().flatMap(newToken => {
                    if (newToken) {
                        headers.set('beare ', newToken);
                        return this.http.post(url, body, headers).take(2);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(initialError);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to throw the error in handlerError method like this

```
handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError("Error message...");
  }
```